# filter dates within a text file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file which has a data in the below format. How can we print only those rows which have a date less than 10 days from the current date?

**sample.txt**

```
system system_data8 Thu Jul 29 22:36:38 2021
system system_data9 Wed Jan 24 14:43:52 2018
system system_data3 Tue Jan 23 20:25:17 2018
system system_data2 Fri Mar 09 20:37:05 2018
system system_data5 Fri Mar 09 22:02:31 2018
```

**expected output**

```
system system_data8 Thu Jul 29 22:36:38 2021
```

I was trying something like below but it's not working.

```
awk -F ' ' '{printf("%s,%s,",$1,$2);"date +%F -d "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7;}' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    tgtDays = 10
    tgtSecs = tgtDays * 24 * 60 * 60

    endTime = strftime("%Y %m %d 12 00 00")
    endSecs = mktime(endTime,1)
}
{
    mthNr   = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$4)+2)/3
    begTime = sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 12 00 00", $7, mthNr, $5)
    begSecs = mktime(begTime,1)
}
(endSecs - begSecs) < tgtSecs
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk sample.txt
system system_data8 Thu Jul 29 22:36:38 2021
```

Note that in the above we replace the time of day in both the input data and the current time with noon because when determining how many days between 2 dates by converting a timestamp to seconds since the epoch first then dividing by the number of seconds in a day you have to use the same time each day because otherwise your "number of days" calculation can/will be thrown off by the time each day.

For example look at the following that's trying to determine if 2 dates which ARE 10 days apart are less than 10 days apart:

```
$ cat diffDatesDemo.awk
BEGIN {
    tgtDays = 10
    tgtSecs = tgtDays * 24 * 60 * 60

    begTime = "2021/08/01 09:00:00"
    endTime = "2021/08/11 08:00:00"

    begDate = gensub(/([ :][0-9]{2}){3}$/,"",1,begTime)
    endDate = gensub(/([ :][0-9]{2}){3}$/,"",1,endTime)

    print "Is", begTime, "less than", tgtDays, "days before", endTime "?"

    ####
    print "\nWrong: Compare 2 timestamps including date plus time of day:"
    begSecs = mktime(gensub("[/:]"," ","g",begTime),1)
    endSecs = mktime(gensub("[/:]"," ","g",endTime),1)

    print begDate, "->", endDate, "is", ((endSecs - begSecs) < tgtSecs ? "<" : ">="), tgtDays, "days"
    ####

    ####
    print "\nRight: Compare 2 dates at the same time each day:"
    begSecs = mktime(gensub("[/:]"," ","g",begDate)" 12 00 00",1)
    endSecs = mktime(gensub("[/:]"," ","g",endDate)" 12 00 00",1)

    print begDate, "->", endDate, "is", ((endSecs - begSecs) < tgtSecs ? "<" : ">="), tgtDays, "days"
    ####
}
```

```
$ awk -f diffDatesDemo.awk
Is 2021/08/01 09:00:00 less than 10 days before 2021/08/11 08:00:00?

Wrong: Compare 2 timestamps including date plus time of day:
2021/08/01 -> 2021/08/11 is < 10 days

Right: Compare 2 dates at the same time each day:
2021/08/01 -> 2021/08/11 is >= 10 days
```

I also used the UTC flag for `mktime()` above to make sure that any local DST changes didn't impact the number of days calculation.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `awk` has time functions:

```
$ gawk -v days=10 'BEGIN {max = days*86400; now = systime()}
NF>3 {
  mn = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$(NF-3)) + 2)/3
  dt = $NF " " mn " " $(NF-2) " " gensub(/:/," ","g",$(NF-1))
  diff = now - mktime(dt)
  if (-max < diff && diff < max)
    print
}' file
system system_data8 Thu Jul 29 22:36:38 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` utility is recent enough and if your shell is `bash` you can do this only with `bash` and `date`:

```
now=$(date +%s)
while read sys sys_d dt; do
  sec=$(date -d "$dt" +%s)
  if (( now-sec <= 10*24*3600 )); then
    echo "$sys $sys_d $dt"
  fi
done < sample.txt
```

> Note that the comparison is done after converting the current date/time to a UNIX timestamp (`date +%s`), that is, seconds since 1970-01-01. Same for the date/time in your file. This does not account for date/time irregularities like daylight saving time or leap seconds. So, depending on when you run this, on the content of your file and on your definition of *10 days*, the result may be what you want or not exactly what you want.